# Firefox Devtools is showing a large Javascript file as undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I have a large compiled *.js* file in my webapp. When I put down a breakpoint or click on an error in the Firefox Devtools console it doesn't load the file in the Sources tab. What's displayed is the text **undefined** instead of the file. What could cause this? Is there a devtools config that's missing?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot, give us more information to reproduce the issue?

Comment: [Screenshot of the bug](https://imgur.com/a/blqQI) It seems to happen when I put a `debugger;` statement in a file that's combined into a very large JavaScript file.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't really help us out. I recommend creating a [mcve] with so that we can reproduce the issue on our end, and diagnose further. ATM, I don't know anything that would simply cause undefined.

Comment: Yeah the I can't post the file that causes this unfortunately. I've tried with other code that I could post but I wasn't able to make another file that causes this.

Comment: If you're unable to reproduce it with other code, start stripping away parts of your code until it works, and you should find your culprit.

Comment: I had the same issue and found that I could get around it by hitting F5 while my cursor was in Developer Tools. After reload it shows the script file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously a bug in the [Firefox Debugger](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html). To get it fixed you should file a bug report on the related issue tracker and attach a minimal test case as FrankerZ pointed out in a comment.

Also, the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) may contain error messages related to this, which should be attached to the bug report to help to fix the issue.